# How to hide a solution in xsim for the student book and display all solutions for the teacher book

Tags: xsim

In my books there are two types of exercises. The first type has public solutions, those solutions should appear in the student's book and teacher's book. The second type has solutions that should only appear in the teacher's book and not in the student's book.

My first approach was to define a boolean "teacherbook" to mark the exercises for the teacher's book.

I also probably need a global variable in the preamble to indicate whether my book should now be printed in student or teacher form.

How do you achieve that?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%Rahmenumgebung
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,xparse}

\usepackage[blank]{xsim}
\xsimsetup{
    print-solutions/headings=false,%no headings before solutions
}
\DeclareExerciseProperty{level}
\DeclareExerciseProperty{symbole}
\DeclareExerciseProperty{notenstufe}
\DeclareExerciseProperty{title}
\DeclareExerciseProperty*{teacherbook}%*=boolean, wenn teacherbook ohne Zuweisung oder wenn teacherbook=true ist, dann soll diese Lösung nur im Teacherbook erscheinen.
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{aufgabe-template}{%
    \IfExistSolutionT{%
        \IfInsideSolutionTF
            {%True
                \label{sol:\ExerciseID}
            }
            {%False
                \label{ex:\ExerciseID}
            }
    }%
    \tcolorbox[
        parbox=false,%wenn dieser Befehl deaktiviert ist, dann sollte unten setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip plus2pt minus2pt} aktiviert sein.
        enhanced jigsaw,
        breakable,%auskommentieren, wenn die Aufgaben in einer einzigen Box zusammenhängen sollen
        left=1mm,%Abstand links zum Rahmen
        right=1mm,%Abstand rechts zum Rahmen
        %colframe=blue!30!white,%Rahmenfarbe
        colframe=black,%Rahmenfarbe
        coltext=black,%Schriftfarbe
        colback=white,%Hintergrundfarbe
        colbacktitle=white,%Hintergrundfarbe im Titel
        coltitle=black,%Schriftfarbe im Titel
        %underlay={%Hintergrund
            %\begin{tcbclipinterior}
            %\shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=white]
            %(interior.north west) circle (2cm);
            %\draw[help lines,step=5mm,white!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            %(interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
            %\end{tcbclipinterior}
        %},
        %drop shadow,%mit Schatten
        beforeafter skip = .5\baselineskip,
        title ={
            \textbf{\GetExerciseName~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%Aufgabe mit Nummer ausgeben
            \GetExercisePropertyT{level}{ \SymAnforderungen{\PropertyValue}}%evtl. Level mit Knödeln anzeigen
            \GetExercisePropertyT{symbole}{ \PropertyValue}%evtl. Symbole anzeigen
            \GetExercisePropertyT{notenstufe}{ (N:~\PropertyValue)}%evtl. Notenstufe anzeigen
            \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{ % notice the space, evtl. Punkte anzeigen
                \mbox{(%
                \printgoal{\PropertyValue}
                \IfExerciseGoalSingularTF{points}
                    {\XSIMtranslate{point}}
                    {\XSIMtranslate{points}}%
                )}%
            }%
            \IfExistSolutionTF%
                {%True bedeutet: Lösung existiert
                    \IfInsideSolutionTF%
                        {%True bedeutet wir sind in der Lösung
                            {\hfill A:~\pageref{ex:\ExerciseID}}%Querverweis zur Aufgabe (A)
                        }
                        {%False
                            {\hfill L:~\pageref{sol:\ExerciseID}}%Querverweis zur Lösung (L)
                        }%
                }%
                {}%False bedeutet Lösung existiert nicht
            \GetExercisePropertyT{title}{\\\PropertyValue}%evtl title in neuer Zeile (\\) ausgeben
        },%
        pad at break*=0mm,%sollte immer letzte Option sein, weil diverse Anpassungen dadurch ausgelöst werden.
    ]
    %nachfolgender Befehl wird nicht gebraucht, wenn mit parbox=false oben gearbeitet wird.
    %\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip plus5pt minus5pt}%
    \IfInsideSolutionT{
        \IfExerciseBooleanPropertyT{teacherbook}{\textcolor{red}{This solution only appears in the student book.}}
    }
}
{%end-Bereich für aufgabe-template
    \endtcolorbox
}
\DeclareExerciseType{Aufgabe}{
    exercise-env = exercise,
    solution-env = solution,
    exercise-name = Aufgabe,
    exercises-name = Aufgaben,
    solution-name = Lösung von Aufgabe,
    solutions-name = Lösungen,
    exercise-template = aufgabe-template,
    solution-template = aufgabe-template,
    within=section,
    %the-counter = \thesection.\arabic{counter-aufgabe}
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}

\chapter{Chapter Title 3}
\section{Section 3.1}
\begin{exercise}[%
    points=1,%
    teacherbook=true%
]
This solution should only visible in the teacher book.
\blindtext[1]
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
\blindtext[1]
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}[%
    points=2%
]
\blindtext[1]
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
\blindtext[1]
\end{solution}


\section{Section limited solutions for students}
\printsolutions[chapter=true]


\chapter{Chapter Title 4}
\section{Section 4.1}
\begin{exercise}[%
    points=1%
]
\blindtext[1]
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
\blindtext[1]
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}[%
    points=1,%
    teacherbook=true%
]
This solution should only visible in the teacher book.
\blindtext[1]
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
\blindtext[1]
\end{solution}


\section{Section all solutions for teachers}
\printsolutions[chapter=true]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If there are more differences between the two versions, consider the multiaudience package.

Comment: Something along those lines might be a solution: https://texwelt.de/fragen/23968/xsim-ubung-losung-zusatzlich-kurzlosung